# How to combine client and server BLE functionality in a single program on ESP32?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

### Goal

Create an application on the ESP32 that uses BLE to send and receive messages from other ESP32 devices running the same program. There is no fixed central server. Once an ESP32 communicates with another, it should put recently contacted ESP32's in a whitelist and not contact them for a period of time.

### My approach

I'm assuming I will need to switch between the client and server roles to be able to achieve my goal. I plan to maintain an array with information of recently contacted ESP32 devices and set a timer for each entry at which point that specific entry will be removed.

### Problem

I've tried the default BLE_client example and BLE_server example, but combining them led to my code not functioning properly and the ESP32 tags not connecting to each other.

What can I do to have my ESP32 devices switch between server and client roles?

Comment: Have a look at this question on github. Someone implemented a server and client in one program: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/3011#issue-470354794

Comment: If that does not help you: could you post your code please?